# How to test saving a resource in a controller with a promise

Tags: angularjs, testing

I have a controller that saves a resource. I can't tell how to "access" the part of the code that executes after the promise resolves. What do I need to change about my test or controller in order to get it to work? Here's the code.

Controller:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name lunchHubApp.controller:AnnouncementsCtrl
 * @description
 * # AnnouncementsCtrl
 * Controller of the lunchHubApp
 */
angular.module('lunchHubApp')
  .controller('AnnouncementsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Announcement', function ($scope, Announcement) {
    $scope.announcements = [];

    $scope.save = function() {

      // This next line is the part I'm finding hard to test.
      new Announcement($scope.announcement).create().then(function(announcement) {
        $scope.foo = 'bar'
      });
    };
  }]);
```

Test:

```
'use strict';

describe('AnnouncementsCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('lunchHubApp', 'ng-token-auth')
  });

  it('sets scope.announcements to an empty array', inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new(),
        ctrl = $controller('AnnouncementsCtrl', { $scope: scope });

    expect(scope.announcements).toEqual([]);
  }));

  describe('save', function() {
    it('works', inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_) {
      var $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      var scope = $rootScope.$new(),
          ctrl = $controller('AnnouncementsCtrl', { $scope: scope });

      expect(scope.announcements.length).toBe(0);

      var announcement = {
        restaurantName: 'Bangkok Taste',
        userId: 1
      };
      scope.announcement = announcement;

      $httpBackend.expect('POST', '/api/announcements').respond(200, announcement);
      scope.save();
      scope.$digest();

      expect(scope.foo).toEqual('bar');
    }));
  });
});
```

**Update:** here's the way I ended up modifying my controller test. The following passes and has been refactored from the original.

```
'use strict';

describe('AnnouncementsCtrl', function() {
  var $httpBackend,
      announcement,
      scope,
      ctrl;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('lunchHubApp');

    inject(function($injector) {
      $httpBackend       = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      scope              = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
      ctrl               = $injector.get('$controller')('AnnouncementsCtrl', { $scope: scope });
      announcement       = { restaurantName: 'Bangkok Taste' };
      scope.announcement = { restaurantName: 'Jason\'s Pizza' };

      $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/api/announcements').respond([announcement]);
    });
  });

  it('sets scope.announcements to an empty array', function() {
    expect(scope.announcements).toEqual([]);
  });

  it('grabs a list of announcements', function() {
    expect(scope.announcements.length).toBe(0);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(scope.announcements.length).toBe(1);
  });

  describe('save', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      $httpBackend.expect('POST', '/api/announcements').respond(200, { restaurantName: 'Foo' });
      scope.save();
      $httpBackend.flush();
    });

    it('adds an announcement', function() {
      expect(scope.announcements.length).toBe(2);
    });

    it('clears the restaurant name', function() {
      expect(scope.announcement.restaurantName).toEqual('');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're doing is good. Since the *Angular resources* are factories using the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service in a *restful way*, you should use the `expect` of the [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) just as you did.

One thing that you miss however is that you need to make sure your promise is resolved. But write async tests can be tricky in some cases. To do so, you have to use the **[flush()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#flush)** method of *$httpBackend* to force your test to be synchronous.

After the flush, you can make your `expect` normally. Also you might have to move your `expectPOST` before your `$rootScope.$new()` statement.

You can go with a change like this, I don't think the `$digest()` is necessary:

```
$httpBackend.expect('POST', '/api/announcements').respond(200, announcement);
scope.save();

$httpBackend.flush();
expect(scope.foo).toEqual('bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

The tests you've started writing seem to be testing not just `AnnouncementsCtrl`, but the `Announcements` service/factory as well. The signs of this in this case are

- You're not mocking the `Announcements` service/factory / not stubbing any of its methods.
- There is no code in the `AnnouncementsCtrl` regarding making http requests, and yet you're using `$httpBackend.expect(...` in the tests for them.
- The success/failure of the tests that claim to test `AnnouncementsCtrl` will succeed or fail depending on code in the `Announcements` service/factory.

This goes against what unit tests are usually used for: testing each component in isolation. Keeping the focus of this answer on testing the success callback passed to the then method of the promise returned by `create`, my suggestion is to mock the `Announcements` service/factory, so its create method returns a promise that you can control in the test. This mock would be of the form:

```
var MockAnnouncement = null;
var deferred = null;
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  MockAnnouncement = function MockAnnouncement() {
    this.create = function() {
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  };
  $provide.value('Announcement', MockAnnouncement);
}));
```

You would then have to make sure that you create deferred object before each test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  deferred = $q.defer(); // Used in MockAnnouncement 
  ctrl = $controller('AnnouncementsCtrl', {
    $scope: $scope
  });
}));
```

This deferred object is then resolved in the test:

```
it('calls create and on success sets $scope.foo="bar"', function() {
  $scope.save();
  deferred.resolve();
  $scope.$apply();
  expect($scope.foo).toBe('bar');
});
```

A slightly extended version of this, testing a few other behaviours of the controller as well, can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/v1bCfmSPmmjBoq3pfDsk

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm going to stick with my originally-selected answer but I think these suggestions will help me write better tests in general. This brought some new things to my attention, so I appreciate that.